# JAX-WS-RI (Metro) with huge heap consumption for big attachments

Tags: java, jax-ws, mtom

We're using JAX-WS-RI to download a document from a SOAP service. The peak heap consumption on client side is huge: to download a 50MB attachment, the jvm requires 1.5GB heap. This is far out.
I googled a lot about this issue. We're already using MTOM request/responses. Streaming is also applied by JAX-WS-RI, I can see the temporary files. HTTP chunking did not help.

With 1GB max heapspace we got an OutOfMemoryError and in the heapdump I can see that JAX-WS, SAAJ is creating millions of String objects for base64 encoding. This introduces the huge overhead.

Any hints/recommendations/workarounds? 
changing the webservice-stack is an option, but not the first one.

Comment: If you're properly using MTOM, then Base64 encoding shouldn't come into the picture - the whole reason for using MTOM is to avoid Base64 encoding which bloats the payload by 1.3x; Resolving this will depend on the point at which the OOME is occurring -  if it's occurring during unmarshalling, you'll need to step in using an interceptor and manually chunk the payload yourself. If it's after unmarshalling, you'll need to work on your service bean implementation and do the chunking there. Post your stacktrace here and we'll see where it's failing